# Using a SAS macro variable to select all values using the IN operator in PROC SQL

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

In a SAS script I have a macro variable which is later used in an SQL `in` statement in a PROC SQL step.

```
%let my_list = (1,2,3);

proc sql;
  select *
  from my_table
  where var1 in &my_list.
;
quit;
```

This works fine, but I need some flexibility and also want to be able to select ALL lines without changing the SQL code itself, but just the macro variable.

**Is there a trick to specifiy the macro variable so it selects ALL lines still using the IN operator?** (avoiding a subquery solution that fills all possible values in the macro variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your code to

```
%let where_clause = var1 in (1,2,3);

proc sql;
  select *
  from my_table
  where &where_clause
;
quit;
```

And change the macro variable to `%let where_clause = 1=1;` in order to select all lines.

```
%let where_clause = 1=1;

proc sql;
  select *
  from my_table
  where &where_clause
;
quit;
```

**OR**, if you are adamant about keeping your code unchanged, you could simply change the macro variable as follows in order for your where clause to always be true:

```
%let my_list = (1) or 1=1;

proc sql;
  select *
  from my_table
  where var1 in &my_list
;
quit;
```

(dirty but gets the job done)

Comment: nice straightforward ideas. I keep thinking too much in procedural programming logic like in R, not the SAS "find and replace" macro approach. Thanks.